# Inline menu with dropdown for responsive

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, responsive-design

I am new to HTML/CSS scene and I am trying to create a inline menu, and on the last, instead of a , I want a image: `<li><img src=""/></li>`, that has a dropdown menu, for easier navigation for mobile (my goal is a responsive menu).

I am probably very lost on the CSS... I appreciate any help or guideness

*The menu preview/example:* https://www.dropbox.com/s/debmbo40qpknawb/example.jpg

*Check the Fiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/csNCe/

**HTML**

```
<header>

            <div class="container clearfix"><a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="We Made You - Future Together" class="logo" width="65" height="21"/></a>
            <span>Stylish</span>

                <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><img src="img/menu.png" id="android" width="50" height="39"/></li>
                        <!--<ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li></li>
                        </ul></li>-->
                </ul>
                </nav>

            </div>

        </header>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
}

.container{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

header .logo{
    float: left;
}

header span{
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

header nav{
    float: right;
}

header .logo{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

header nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 20px;
    line-height: 36px;
}

header nav li{
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header nav li{
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header nav ul li a{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

header nav ul li:hover{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #303030;
}

header nav ul li a:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!  You used tags that contained typos.

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<header>
    <img src="http://www.socialtalent.co/images/blog-content/so-logo.png"/>   
<div id="menu">
        <div id="v"> <a href="#">home</a></div>
        <div id="v"> <a href="#">portafolio</a></div>
        <div id="v"> <a href="#">about</a></div>
        <div class="ui-icon">
           <div id="sub">
                <a href="#">submenu</a>
                <a href="#">submenu2</a>
                <a href="#">submenu3</a>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
</header>
```

css

```
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 59px;
    background: green;
}
img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
}
.ui-icon{
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://cdn-img.easyicon.net/png/10747/1074745.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: 2px 8px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 45px;
    right: 40px;
    top: 14px;
}
#menu{
     background: #222;
     float:right;
     width: 350px;
     height: 59px;
     margin: 0 25px 0 0;}
#v{
     color:#fff;
     display:inline-block;
     margin: 18px 0 0 0;
     }
a{
     font-size:14px;
     display:block;
     text-decoration:none;
     font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-weight:normal;
     color: white; 
     padding:0 25px 10px 25px;}
a:hover{
     color:#444;
     text-decoration:none;}
.ui-icon:hover #sub{
     display:block;
              }
#sub:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: transparent;
    top:-20px;
    right: 0;
}
#sub:before {
right: 16px;
content: '';
position: absolute;
margin: -18px 0 0 0;
border-top: none;
border-right: 8px solid transparent;
border-left: 8px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 8px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#sub{
     width:100px;
     margin: 53px 70px 0 -70px;
     padding: 10px;
     background:#ccc;
     display:none;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:2;}
```

Comment: Works but disappears as soon as you try to press one of the submenu links

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        <div class="container clearfix"><a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="We Made You - Future Together" class="logo" width="65" height="21"/></a>
        <span>Stylish</span>

            <ul class="mainmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                 <li><img src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/photos/img/photos/private/AIbEiAIAAABECODY0r_3mprz2AEiC3ZjYXJkX3Bob3RvKigyMDFiNjk1ODlmNzVhN2E2NDRiOWY1NjkzOWVmZTUzMDUxNjUyOWVkMAHZmRD1ZZjPufQO9TfzylPzSSTCFg" id="android" width="50" height="39"/></li>

                    <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>


        </div>

    </header>
```

Add add the below css to your css file

```
.mainmenu {
    width:400px;text-align:left;display:block;position:relative;top:50px;
}

.submenu {
    display:none;
}

.mainmenu:hover .submenu{
    display:block;
}
```

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: It's almost, but I dont want the dropdown menu linked to all ´<li a>´ (the links inline), I just wanted it linked to the ´<li> <img src="">´

Comment: I tried the code on the Fiddle file, can you try to fix it and send it , I cant understand the semantic